# PHP - Attaching Text File - Mail Not Working

Tags: php, email

I am writing an application that is to send an email that contains a CSV as an attachment. However, it is not working. The mail function does not return false (implying that it succeeded); however, the email is not being sent.

I have sent/received email from the server before, so I do not believe that is the issue. However, I do not really have any experience with sending attachments through PHP, so I would suspect the issue lies in there. I have followed this tutorial to an extent: http://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/post/56-send-an-email-attachment-with-php/

Here are some code snippets:

```
$file = tmpfile();

// code omitted

$fileArray = array(); // this gets filled with more arrays/lines of data


// code omitted


try {

foreach($fileArray as $line) {
var_dump($line);
fputcsv($file, $line);
}

// begin mailing
$toEmail = 'myemail';
$subject = "Insurance Registration";

fseek($file, 0);
$attachData = fread($file, 1024);
$fileName = $lastName . "_" . date('Y');
$random = md5(time());
$boundary =  "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$random}x";
$headers = "From: Test \nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed\n" . "boundary=\"{$boundary}\"";
$message = "Testing!.\n\n " . "-{$boundary}\n " . "Content-Type= text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding 7bit\n\n " . "Testing Again " . "\n\n ";
$attachData = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachData));
$message .= "--{$boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain;\n" . "name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . " . Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $attachData . "\n\n" . "-{$boundary}-\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $message, $headers)) { 
} else {
$hasError = true;
}

if($hasError) {
echo "<h2>Error Submitting form. Please check your input and try again</h2>";
} else {
header('Location: success.php');
}
```

I get redirected to the success page, but never receive an email. Thanks!

Comment: Check spam folder. might also be a server configuration issue.

Comment: Check your spam. `if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $message, $headers)) { echo "Mail sent"; }` if you see "Mail sent", then it did its job. If it ends up in spam, then you can try setting up an SPF record which will help reduce messages possibly marked as spam and/or rejected altogether.

Comment: Plus, try getting rid of `if($hasError) {
echo "<h2>Error Submitting form. Please check your input and try again</h2>";
} else {
header('Location: success.php');
}` and just do as I shown you above. I doubt it's even making it there anyway.

Comment: I'll leave you with this last comment http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php